# Best web-app solution for searching subversion repository documents?

Tags: document-indexing, subversion, search, text-search

I was simply wondering what tool would be the most appropriate for indexing and searching the text of multiple standard document types (i.e doc/ppt/xls/pdf).

I've had a look at OpenGrok, however it seems to be specialised for code searching and standard text documents (it does have PDF), and I've also taken a look at ReposSearch, however I am interested to know if anyone has some solid recommendations. This is a subversion repository.